# Expression syntax using processing.run algorithms in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-expression

I am trying to run "Extract by expression" in a QGIS script using processing.run

```
layer1 = points.shp
processing.run(
    'qgis:extractbyexpression',
    {
        'EXPRESSION': "array_contains(aggregate(layer1,array_agg, field1),field2)",
        'INPUT': layer2,
        'OUTPUT':os.path.join(fold,'OneName.shp')
    }
)
```

The expression selects features from layer2 based on layer1. I ran the algorithm from the GUI and everything works fine. I copied/pasted the expression from the GUI, but in the script is not working, the resulting file is empty.

It happens the same with "Geometry by expression"

```
expr = "with_variable ('no',20,collect_geometries (array_foreach
(generate_series (0,@no-1,1),
line_interpolate_point($geometry, length($geometry) / @no * @element))))"

new_points = processing.run(
    'native:geometrybyexpression'
    {
        'INPUT':line,
        'OUTPUT_GEOMETRY':2,
        'EXPRESSION' : expr,
        'OUTPUT':os.path.join(fold,'NewPoints.shp')
    }
)
```

Here I add same number of points for each line. As before, it works from GUI but not from the script. I guess there is something I am missing with the expressions syntax, but I couldn't figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure about the line "layer1 = points.shp" ? or is-it a wrong copy/paste and it's "points.shp" as a string ? But for sure, in your expression, you must have a layer in QGIS project called `layer1` literally. The QGIS expression won't understand if you want to refer to the Python variable called `layer1`. There is a difference between inside the QGIS expression as string and Python variables. Please add some details about the input `points.shp`.

Comment: Did you look to existing questions like `expression pyqgis processing` such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=expression+pyqgis+processing ?